# How does Obi-Wan owe one to Anakin if he doesn't get saved?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Anakin says to Obi-Wan:

> Anakin: All right. But you **owe me one**, and not for saving your skin
> for the tenth time.

How does Obi-Wan owe one to Anakin if he doesn't get saved ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He *owes him* for 'taking the hit', e.g. spending a very long and boring afternoon with the politicians (as they heap praise on him and make endless dull speeches) while Obi-Wan gets to do something useful, heading off to debrief the Jedi Council and work on their next mission.

> “This whole operation was your idea,” Anakin said to Obi-Wan. “You
> planned it. You have to be the one to take the bows this time.”
>
> “Sorry, old friend,” Obi-Wan said. “You killed Count Dooku.” Anakin
> winced, but Obi-Wan didn’t notice. He went on, “You rescued the
> Chancellor, and you managed to land that bucket of bolts safely. You
> —”
>
> “Only because of your training, Master,” Anakin said earnestly. “You
> deserve all those speeches.” And I certainly don’t want praise for the
> way I killed Dooku.
>
> **“Those endless speeches.” Obi-Wan shook his head. “Anakin, let’s face
> it — you are the hero this time. It’s your turn to spend a glorious
> day with the politicians.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Anakin in this case is saying that Obi-Wan owes him because he is spending the time with the politicians. His "saving your skin" comment is referencing his unwillingness to leave Obi-Wan behind on the Separatist cruiser, which saved Obi-Wan's life as Anakin had to crash land the ship.